# How to Properly Support English when Localizing an App?

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I'm working on localizing an Android app.

For arguments sake, let's say the app will support English, Albanian, and Bengali.

Currently all English strings are listed in the "default value" column of the translations editor:

[image]

Apps on the app store generally state what locales they support.

I'm assuming when you submit an app that either a person or machine verifies your claims... so...

Is it necessary *to explicitly add English* (en) locale/column *in addition* to the default values (just as Albanian and Bengali have been added in the photo) in order for the app to be considered to officially "support" English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to add English locale to have it in Supported Language menu. Check [documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support) out.

> When your Java code refers to strings, the system would load strings from the default (en_US) resource file, even if the app has Spanish resources localized under es_ES. This is because when the system cannot find an exact match, it continues to look for resources by stripping the country code off the locale. Finally, if no match is found, the system falls back to the default, which is en_US.
>
> The system would also default to en_US if the user chose a language that the app didn't support at all, like French.

Default locale is `en_US`.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

> Apps on the app store generally state what locales they support.

If you are talking about Apple's App Store, Google Play won't list the supported languages in similar fashion.

[image: supported languages listing in App Store]

However, you can localize the store listing page. According to play console help, If a user's language preference matches the translation languages you've added, they'll see your app's translated version. You can also add localized graphic assets for your store listing pages. See [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en) for more. This feature is similar to App Store's [metadata localization](https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206919477-List-of-languages-supported-by-iTunes-App-Store-for-app-description-).

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy solution to your problem.

Just find the path in your project:

> res/

and add a folder named:

> values-en

Then add a file named:

> strings.xml

Finally, it will look like this:

> res/values-en/strings.xml

And the resources in it will show when the user's language setting is English.

Comment: This explains how to add a locale.  This doesn't answer the question of whether or not it is necessary to explicitly add English in addition to (English) "default."